# Azure Devops stage status badges which includes version (tag)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Is it possible for Azure Devops status badges to be used to show the latest tag (version) for any specific stage?

I don't want to specify a branch, I do however want to be able to show which tag is deployed in which environment (stage).

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible... out-of-the-box...

For the Azure pipelines their is a (long running) open ticket, that looks a lot like what you want:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/badge-image-showing-the-deployed-version-of-each-s/728341

### Alternative

There is however a possibility with [Badgen.net](https://badgen.net/), if your project is accessible. Please take a look at the link below for the DevOps possiblities:

https://badgen.net/azure-pipelines